# Is Conger's kappa available in Stata?

Tags: stata

Is the [modified version of kappa](http://www.agreestat.com/blog_irr/kappa_coefficient_for_multiple_raters.html) proposed by Conger (1980) available in Stata?  Tried to google it to no avail.

Comment: Doesn't the native `kappa` command handle the multiple rater case?

Comment: There are problems, with that dimitriy refer to the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no one has responded with a Stata solution, I developed some code to calculate Conger's kappa using the formulas provided in Gwet, K. L. (2012). *Handbook of Inter-Rater Reliability* (3rd ed.), Gaithersburg, MD: Advanced Analytics, LLC.  See especially pp. 34-35.

My code is undoubtedly not as efficient as others could write, and I would welcome any improvements to the code or to the program format that others wish to make.

```
cap prog drop congerkappa
prog def congerkappa
  * This program has only been tested with Stata 11.2, 12.1, and 13.0.
  preserve
  * Number of judges
  scalar judgesnum = _N 
  * Subject IDs
  quietly ds
  local vlist `r(varlist)'
  local removeit = word("`vlist'",1)
  local targets: list vlist - removeit  
  * Sums of ratings by each judge
  egen judgesum = rowtotal(`targets')  
  * Sum of each target's ratings
  foreach i in `targets' {
    quietly summarize `i', meanonly
    scalar mean`i' = r(mean)
    }  
  * % each target rating of all target ratings  
  foreach i in `targets' {
    gen `i'2 = `i'/judgesum
    }  
  * Variance of each target's % ratings  
  foreach i in `targets' {
    quietly summarize `i'2 
    scalar s2`i'2 = r(Var)
    }  
  * Mean variance of each target's % ratings
  foreach i in `targets' {
    quietly summarize `i'2, meanonly
    scalar mean`i'2 = r(mean)
    }  
  * Square of mean of each target's % ratings  
  foreach i in `targets' {
    scalar mean`i'2sq = mean`i'2^2
    }    
  * Sum of variances of each target's % ratings
  scalar sumvar = 0
  foreach i in `targets' {
    scalar sumvar = sumvar + s2`i'2
    }    
  * Sum of means of each target's % ratings
  scalar summeans = 0
  foreach i in `targets' {
    scalar summeans = summeans + mean`i'2
    }   
  * Sum of meansquares of each target's % ratings
  scalar summeansqs = 0
  foreach i in `targets' {
    scalar summeansqs = summeansqs + mean`i'2sq
    } 
  * Conger's kappa
  scalar conkappa = summeansqs -(sumvar/judgesnum)
  di _n "Conger's kappa = "  conkappa
  restore
  end
```

The data structure required by the program is shown below.  The variable names are not fixed, but the judge/rater variable must be in the first position in the data set.  The data set should not include any variables other than the judge/rater and targets/ratings.

```
 Judge    S1   S2   S3   S4   S5   S6 
 Rater1    2    4    2    1    1    4 
 Rater2    2    3    2    2    2    3 
 Rater3    2    5    3    3    3    5 
 Rater4    3    3    2    3    2    3
```

If you would like to run this against a test data set, you can use the judges data set from StataCorp and reshape it as shown.

```
use http://www.stata-press.com/data/r12/judges.dta, clear
sort judge
list, sepby(judge)
reshape wide rating, i(judge) j(target)
rename rating* S*
list, noobs

* Run congerkappa program on demo data set in memory
congerkappa
```

I have run only a single validation test of this code against the data in Table 2.16 in Gwet (p. 35) and have replicated the Conger's kappa = .23343 as calculated by Gwet on p. 34.  Please test this code on other data with known Conger's kappas before relying on it.

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but in case anyone is still looking--the SSC package `kappaetc` now calculates that, along with every other inter-rater statistic you could ever want.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Conger's kappa for multiple raters is available in Stata, but it is available in R via the `irr` package, using the `kappam.fleiss` function and specifying the `exact` option.  For information on the `irr` package in R, see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/irr/irr.pdf#page.12 .

After installing and loading the `irr` package in R, you can view a demo data set and Conger's kappa calculation using the following code.

```
data(diagnoses)
print(diagnoses)
kappam.fleiss(diagnoses, exact=TRUE)
```

I hope someone else here can help with a Stata solution, as you requested, but this may at least provide a solution if you can't find it in Stata.

Answer (score -1):

In response to Dimitriy's comment below, I believe Stata's native `kappa` command applies either to two unique raters or to more than two non-unique raters.

The original poster may also want to consider the `icc` command in Stata, which allows for multiple unique raters.

Comment: Do I need to transpose the data to have the raters as variables in stata if I use icc? Furthermore ICC is parametric, so normal distribution would be desirable.. am I correct?